# I'm only getting one object back from a Get Request. How to retrieve all of it?

Tags: ios, swift, get, alamofire

I'm only getting one object back from a Get Request. How do I retrieve all of them? Here is my Data Model.

```
class DataClass {

// MARK VARIABLES
init(price: Double, title: String, firstImage: String, allImages: [String]) {

    _price = Price
    _title = title
    _allImages = allImages
    _firstImg = firstImage
}


 var _title: String!
 var _firstImg: String!
 var _allImages: [String]!
 var _propertyPrice: Double!

func downloadHandMProperties(completed: @escaping downloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(propertyListing).responseJSON { response in
        if let result = response.result.value {
         let dict = JSON(result)
           if let data = dict["data"].dictionary {

               if let listingResultDict = data["listings"]?.array  {

                  for list in listingResultDict {

                        if let propertyName = list["data"]["name"].string {
                           self._title = propertyName

           /etc..
           // I parsed all of the data and passed them to the variables. 

        completed()

    }
}
```

Here is the ViewController from where I'm receiving it.

```
Class ViewController: UIViewController {
  let array = [DataClass]()
 var property = DataClass(price: 0, title: "", firstImage: "", allImages: [])

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let data = DataClass(price: property.price, title: property.title, firstImage: property.firstImage, allImages: property.allImages)
    self.array.append(data)
   print(array)
 }
}
```

There is only one object in that array. How do I get all of them. I thought of looping through the results, but I can only loop through Arrays and Dictionaries, and the Object is neither. Any suggestions as to how to retrieve all of the objects and put them in to the array?

Comment: Is your issue that you're getting back one big JSON object that contains all of your `propertyListings` or is it that you are only getting one `propertyListing` item back and you're wondering where the others are?

Comment: I'm only getting back one propertyListing and I'm wondering where the rest of them are.

Comment: then are you sure you're hitting the correct endpoint when you call `Alamofire.request(propertyListing).responseJSON`? You might be going one node too deep and targeting just one `propertyListing` instead of getting its parent node which would logically contain all the listings.

Comment: So when I print out the variables in the data model, I get everything. But when its goes to the viewController, it only returns the last object out of 20 or so. I've gotten the code to work before, but I had to put my GET request in my ViewController and loop through all of the listings. Unfortunately I want to be able to access the properties from many ViewControllers, so that way would not work.

Comment: see my answer below and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your `result` object as collection type that you can loop through. You'll have to figure out what you can cast your `result` object as with some trial and error but it could look something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(propertyListing).responseJSON { response in
    if let result = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
       //here the result object is casted as an array of [String: Any] dictionaries

       // I parsed all of the data and passed them to the variables. 
    }
    completed()

}
```

Then you could loop through the array of dictionaries since each dictionary would represent one of your objects.

What you could do to test out what type you could cast your `result` object as is add a break point on the `if let result = response.result.value {` line of code and then run `po response.result.value as? [[String: Any]]` in the xcode console. If you get a good looking result printed out you're set!

Comment: I just edited my post a little. I included my SwiftyJson conversion to the [String: Any]. It takes care of that for me. I just didn't include because I didn't think it was relevant. I don't think that is the problem.